# Obfuscate emails in MySQL dump file

Tags: python, mysql, regex

I'm new to Python and stuck with simple task which is now looks not simple at all.

So basically the idea is to provide an obfuscated MySQL dump to Dev team.

The dump is full of INSERT statements with client emails and the idea is to replace usernames with some random hashes (random is important because of UNIQ indexes) and to replace domain name as well.

I tried to use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), it does the job but only if there is one regex match per line. Unfortunately, INSERT statements have lots of emails in one line, so I'm wondering am I missing something?

Basically, here is a data sample:

```
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('john','john@gmail.com','\0'),('kate','kate@yahoo.com','\0'),
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('peter','peter@gmail.com','\0'),
```

Current result:

```
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('john','-**5196869426929071700**@example.com','\0'),('kate','-**5196869426929071700**@example.com','\0'),
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('peter','-4574418619379266923@example.com','\0'),
```

The desired output:

```
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('john','-**5196869426929071700**@example.com','\0'),('kate','-**7140769694376981046**@example.com','\0'),
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('peter','-4574418619379266923@example.com','\0'),
```

My code:

```
import re

with open("dump.sql", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

def repl(match):
    output = str(hash(line)) + "@example.com"
    return output

new_lines = []
for line in lines:
    new_lines.append(re.sub('([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,})', repl, line))

with open("dump-processed.sql", "w") as file:
    file.writelines(new_lines)
```

Any thoughts on this issue are really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use `mysqldump --skip-extended-insert` to disable multi-row INSERTs. The output of the dump will have just one row of data per INSERT.

Comment: @BillKarwin, Well, this mysqldump parameter made my python code works, thanks a lot! 
But I'm still curious though is it possible to achieve the desired output using python code because the amount of time to upload the obfuscated dump have increased significantly.

Answer (score 0):

What happens between creating the dump and someone seeing the obfuscated emails?

Here is a thought:

1. Take the dump
2. Load the dump into a separate table(s) (or database, or even server)
3. UPDATE table SET email = MD5(email);
4. Move that table(s) to its ultimate location.

What are the goals?

If the email column needs to be consistent between tables and for the same email to show up as the same hash in different rows, this achieves such.

For example, 'john@gmail.com' is consistently and uniquely turned into '1f9d9a9efc2f523b2f09629444632b5c'.

If you need to look at the name and domain separately, my approach needs some work.  But so does your "example.com";.

Comment: The goal is to setup a cronjob to automate database upload to the Dev environment.
So logic is:
1. Take a dump.

Comment: 2. Run obfuscation script.
3. Load the dump into dev environment.

The mysqldump --skip-extended-insert parameter proposed by @BillKarwin made my code works but unfortunately the amount of time to load the updated dump have increased significantly.

So I'm still trying to figure out how to do this using python and regular MySQL dump.

P.S. Thanks for the suggestion to use UPDATE table SET email = MD5(email);, it is an interesting idea.

Comment: `--skip-extended-insert` will hurt performance -- perhaps ten-fold!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mysqldump --tab` to dump CSV data files instead of SQL. Then do your obfuscation on the CSV data.

Importing these files is a little more complex. You'd recreate the tables, then use `mysqlimport` one table at a time.

You need to write some script to loop over the tables, but the advantage is that the import would be much faster than importing by running SQL files.